# Creating a table that stores Distances and other column

Tags: postgresql, distance, postgis-2.2

I am looking to run a query to calculate the distance from a polygon to other features (will use this query on point, polygon, and line features) within 2 miles and create a table that will display multiple columns:

- Polygonid
- nearfeature_dist
- nearfeature_name

Currently I have:

```
CREATE TABLE near_fiber AS
SELECT parcels.objectid,
```

Not sure what postgis function I should use to get my intended results. Im thinking a mix between ST_Distance and ST_DWithin.

I will have to use this query multiple time for different features.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to reference the table twice and use different conditions. One condition with the distance and one with the polygonid you want to have calculated.

The result you safe as a new table. You get a new geometry with the objects within your search distance(plus the chosen feature) and the distances as a column.

```
CREATE TABLE polygon1 AS
  SELECT 
    original_table.geom as geom,
    polygonid,
    nearfeaturename,
    ST_Distance(original_table.geom, single_polygon.geom) as nearfeature_dist
  FROM original_table, original_table as single_polygon
  WHERE ST_Distance(original_table.geom, single_polygon.geom) < 2000 AND single_polygon.polygonid = 1
```

Comment: I have an error for missing FROM clause on line 4

Comment: Had a missing FROM entry, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work and give you good performance.

```
CREATE TABLE near_fiber AS
SELECT table2.polygon_id, table2.nearest_dist, table2.nearest_name
FROM table1, 
LATERAL (SELECT DISTICT ON (polygon_id) polygon_id,
ST_Distance(table1.geom,table2.geom) nearest_dist, table2.name nearest_name 
FROM table2 WHERE ST_DWithin(table1.geom,table2.geom,2)
/*Depending on what projection you are using, the distance in ST_Dwithin
should be represtnted in the unit of that projection */
ORDER BY table1.polygon_id, table1.geom <-> table2.geom) table2;
```

The syntax in complicated and ugly. That is because the knn operator <-> only uses spatial index when feeded with one constant geometry. Using lateral in this way is a hack for that.

If you have a big data set and can except not to only get results within 2 miles but within a bounding box that is expanded by 2 miles you can speed upp the query  a lot by some rewriting. The slowest part of this query is the second internal step of ST_Dwithin. That is a non index-based distance check if the geometries is really max 2 miles apart.